# Does a router need to change any field(s) in an incoming IP packet before sending it out on an outgoing link? Why?

Tags: tcp, ip, router, packet

Does a router need to change any field(s) in an incoming IP packet before sending it out on
an outgoing link? Why?

Answer (score 1):

At least the TTL (IPv4) and hop limit (IPv6) need to be decremented to avoid routing loops. And in case of NAT (i.e. private internal IP, public external IP) the source IP address and port need to be changed to reflect the new outgoing source IP address and to make it possible to map replies back to the original internal IP and port. In this case of course the TCP checksum needs to be adapted too since it includes these changed information.